# How to add spaces in between words with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

So this is my version of the code `let str = addOne + " " + addTwo + " " + addThree + " " + addFour + " " + addFive`

Is there a simpler approach to adding spaces when combining strings?

Comment: My way seems kind of repetitive and impractical. What if I had to combine tons of strings together and add spaces in between?

Comment: "addOne", "addTwo" ... are same word ? Because I don't see better way if not

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask), [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask), and [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic)

Comment: do you have an array of string, can you be more specific ?

Comment: `let str = [addOne, addTwo, addThree, addFour, addFive].join(' ');` However, it depends on what these individual variables are: perhaps instead of storing them in 5 separate variables, you can nip the issue at the bud and just directly create the string from the original data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [Template literals (Template Strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
let str = `${addOne} ${addTwo}`
```